# Unable to launch Netty server on Android 4.0 device

Tags: android, netty

Using Netty 3.5.6 on a unrooted Android 4.0.1 galaxy Nexus.  Attempting to run a Netty server on the device.  I have  in my manifest.

Server bind code:

```
rtspSA= new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),544);
Channel rtspChannel = bootstrap.bind(rtspSA);
allChannels.add(rtspChannel);
```

I get two errors:

```
E/dalvikvm( 8884): Could not find class 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue', referenced from method org.jboss.netty.util.intenal.QueueFactory.createQueue
```

and

```
E/NettyServer( 8884): org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: localhost/127.0.0.1:544
E/NettyServer( 8884): Caused by: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

reading through Stackoverflow it sounded like the first one was fixed: [Netty 3.4.1.Final does not work on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311885/netty-3-4-1-final-does-not-work-on-android)

the second issue is likely a permissions problem but I cannot deduce which permission I am missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the uses internet permissions in my manifest file

Comment: partial answer to question.  Port 544 was already bound by another process.  Still looking for help on the class not found problem

Comment: "Using Netty 3.5.6 on a unrooted Android..." <-- I guess you mean Netty 3.4.6. The latest Netty 3.5 is still Beta1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same problem as you and found a partial solution here:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/272

something on this part:

```
You can now disable it via a system property.
3.x:
-Dorg.jboss.netty.tryUnsafe=false    
4.x
-Dio.netty.tryUnsafe=false
By default it will try to use Unsafe.
```

I'm included

```
    System.setproperty(new property(" _ but I'm not sure what goes in here _"))
```

on my code, but I'm still not sure it's working, maybe the wrong string or to do with:

```
It also can help if you have a custom ClassLoader in place or try to run in a non oracle/sun jdk.
```

It's a direction towards making it work, but I'm not sure how to carry on, if anyone have the next piece on the puzzle will be greatly appreciated.